# how to extend bounding box regionprops from matlab

Tags: matlab, bounding-box

in matlab function regionprops()

I created bounding box from image by

```
obj = regionprops(obj_label, 'BoundingBox');
```

since it will return the smallest area bounding box bask on binary input mask on that

The question is if I want to increase the area bounding box ( like add some addition all width and height by 5 pixel) from that information how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly you may want to look into [imdilate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html). If you have a mask you are using you can pass it into this and it should get the desired effect.

If this is not what you're looking for could you please clarify what variables you have and what variables you wish to have. This would be very helpful in formulating an answer.